# Grouping data by date in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have my json file as below.

```
  {
  "components":{
  "record1":
  [
  {
    "date":1419038000,
    "name":"Vinay",
    "status":"false"

  },
  {
    "date":1419034102,
    "name":"Ajay",
    "status":"true"
  }
  ],
  "record2":[
    {
    "date":1619037000,
    "name":"Soumya",
    "status":"true"
  },
  {
    "date":1419038000,
    "name":"Savio",
    "status":"false"
  }
  ]
}
}
```

This is my js file:

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",['angular.filter']);

app.controller("Control",function($scope,$http){
   $scope.output=[];

   $http.get('myData.json').
       success(function(data){
        $scope.tableData = data.components;
        for(var i in Object.keys($scope.tableData)){

          for(var j in $scope.tableData[Object.keys($scope.tableData)[i]]){

                $scope.output.push($scope.tableData[Object.keys($scope.tableData)[i]][j]);
              }

        }
        console.log($scope.output);
    });
});
```

I want to group the above data from both array of objects only according to date from the given timestamp into a table. I have attached the link for the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRNHz.png)

Comment: When you receive data, map it into nested structure based on dates and pass that new array to view

Comment: sorry I didn't get you. What nested structure do you actually mean? I have edited my code a little. So please see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like as follows:

```
// create object whose keys are dates
// produces {'2012-11-11':{date: DateObj, items:[{name:...},{..}]}, '2014-09-02':{date:....}, ...}
var dateGroupObj =  Object.keys(data.components).reduce(function(a, c){
    data.components[c].forEach(function(item){
      var date=  new Date(item.abc*1000);
      var dateStr = date.toISOString().slice(0,10);
      a[dateStr] = a[dateStr] ? a[dateStr] : {date: new Date(dateStr), items:[]};
      a[dateStr].items.push(item);         
    });
    return a;
  },{});
 // map above object to array to allow sorting, filtering etc 
 $scope.dateGroups = Object.keys(dateGroupObj).map(function(key){
   return dateGroupObj[key];
 });
```

View

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="group in dateGroups | orderBy:'date'">
    <tr ng-repeat="item in group.items">
      <td rowspan="{{group.items.length+1}}" ng-if="$index==0">{{group.date|date}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/M1iXbaIXYSDzG3gvxiJi?p=preview)**</kbd>